# jQuery form submission issue

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I am trying to submit inside of fancybox (www.fancybox.net). If I go directly to the form it will submit fine. However, if I load the form inside of the page I want to call fancybox from the form will not submit and fancybox goes away and the page refreshes. I have tried both fancybox and facebox to same issue.. below is the Jquery code I have all in the main page. This page opens fancybox and subsquently the form for submission. The form is supposed to show a thank you message from in the window when it submits instead of refreshing the page.. Any help is much appreciated:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#various1").fancybox({
        'opacity': true,
        'overlayShow': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'autoscale': 'false',
        'transitionOut': 'none'
    });

    $("submit").submit(function () {
        alert('it submits');

        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var name = $('#name').attr('value');
        var email = $('#email').attr('value');
        var password = $('#password').attr('value');
        var custom1 = $('#custom1').attr('value');
        var custom2 = $('#custom2').attr('value');
        var custom3 = $('#custom3').attr('value');
        var custom4 = $('#custom4').attr('value');
        var custom5 = $('#custom5').attr('value');
        var custom6 = $('#custom6').attr('value');
        var custom7 = $('#custom7').attr('value');
        var custom8 = $('#custom8').attr('value');
        var custom9 = $('#custom9').attr('value');
        var custom10 = $('#custom10').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: "name=" + name + "& email=" + email + "& password=" + password + "& custom1=" + custom1 + "& custom2=" + custom2 + "& custom3=" + custom3 + "& custom4=" + custom4 + "& custom5=" + custom5 + "& custom6=" + custom6 + "& custom7=" + custom7 + "& custom8=" + custom8 + "& custom9=" + custom9 + "& custom10=" + custom10,

            success: function () {

                $('submit').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('div.success').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

;
});

Link to form:

```
<a id="various1" href="register.php">
```

Comment: i dont see an error in actual code, where is the link to working example gone?

Comment: You shouldn't use `.attr('value')` - jQuery has `.val()` for a reason. Also, http://jsbeautifier.org/ is a great thing to format your code before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "name=" + name + "& email=" + email + "& password=" + password + "& custom1=" + custom1 + "& custom2=" + custom2 + "& custom3=" + custom3 + "& custom4=" + custom4 + "& custom5=" + custom5 + "& custom6=" + custom6 + "& custom7=" + custom7 + "& custom8=" + custom8 + "& custom9=" + custom9 + "& custom10=" + custom10,
```

That's so wrong, incorrect and ugly. There shouldn't be spaces after `&`. Actually, passing a string there is already bad. Pass an object like this:

```
var data = { name: name, email: email, password: password, custom1: custom1, ... };
```

using `data: data`

Here's the fixed version:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#various1").fancybox({
        'opacity': true,
        'overlayShow': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'autoscale': 'false',
        'transitionOut': 'none'
    });

    $("form").submit(function () {
        var data = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            custom1: $('#custom1').val(),
            custom2: $('#custom2').val(),
            custom3: $('#custom3').val(),
            custom4: $('#custom4').val(),
            custom5: $('#custom5').val(),
            custom6: $('#custom6').val(),
            custom7: $('#custom7').val(),
            custom8: $('#custom8').val(),
            custom9: $('#custom9').val(),
            custom10: $('#custom10').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                $('submit').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('div.success').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

You should really use the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit that form though.. Saves you a lot of work typing all the field names...

Comment: DANGIT! Beat me to posting it. Anyway, all I have to add is that he should use $.serialize() to send along his form data - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ - it's a lot of hassle to manually enter all those inputs in case he need to change them on the fly.

Comment: Indeed. Or even use the awesome [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: Thanks for comments guys will try advice.. Sorry for ugliness.. I found the code online and just getting started with jQuery..